# What are the statistical implications of combining two categorical variables into one

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, categorical-data, linear-model

Please forgive me, my understanding of statistics is a work in progress.
To illustrate my question, here is a simplified scenario. A linear mixed model has the form:
lmer(var6 ~ Life Stage * Sex * var3 + var4 + (1|var5)).

Life Stage: categorical with 2 levels Adult, Juvenile ;
Sex: categorical with 2 levels Male, Female ;
Var 3: numeric range 1-100 ;
var 4: numeric ;
var 5: character ;
var 6: numeric

There is an experimental reason why a 3 way interaction between these variables is appropriate.
Running the model gives the warning message that the model is rank deficient and 1 coefficient has to be dropped. I am expecting that the interaction of Adult Males with var3 will be different to that of Adult Female, Juvenile Male and Juvenile Female, but that these three won't be different from each other. Running the model without the interaction gives no warning.

In this case, would it be ok to combine Sex and Age into a new categorical variable with 4 levels: Adult M, Adult F, Juv M, Juv F. Or am I being naive and there is a glaring reason why this would be statistically inappropriate. Doing so removes the warning that the model is rank deficient.

The model is then being used for prediction which is why the warning can't be ignored (or so I believe, happy to be told otherwise).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it per se, but you might want to look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090722/lme4lmer-reports-fixed-effect-model-matrix-is-rank-deficient-do-i-need-a-fi
and this page: https://juliastats.org/MixedModels.jl/dev/rankdeficiency/

Comment: "my understanding of statistics is a work in progress" ... so it is with us all.